# Inverse of sum of two matrix inverses

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, positive-definite

$A$ is a positive definite matrix and $B$ is a positive diagonal matrix. We want to figure out the inverse of the sum of inverses of $A+B$, namely
$(A^{-1}+B^{-1})^{-1}$.
Is it correct to apply the following general matrices identity? 
$$(A^{-1}+B^{-1})^{-1}=B(A+B)^{-1}A.$$
Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you multiply the right hand side with $A^{-1} + B^{-1}$ and see what comes out?

Comment: Thank you Arin for your hint.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1505628/321264

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can easily prove the identity $A^{-1} + B^{-1} = A^{-1}(A+B)B^{-1}$ (pre- multiply with $A$ and post-multiply with $B$ and recall the matrix addition is commutative). Now since $A$ is positive definite it is invertible (definition) and since $B$ is positive diagonal its determinant $\text{det}(B) = \prod_i b_{ii}$ is bigger than zero hence it also invertible. One thing to note is that the sum $A+B$ does not have to be invertible (take $A = -I_n$ and $B = I_n$), but for these $A$ and $B$ it is. Since $A+B$ is invertible, $(A^{-1} + B^{-1})^{-1}$ is also because it is the product of invertible matrices. The inverse is then given by \begin{align*}
(A^{-1} + B^{-1})^{-1} = \big( A^{-1}(A+B)B^{-1} \big)^{-1} = B(A+B)^{-1}A.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

As already commented, why not check?:

$$\left(A^{-1}+B^{-1}\right)\cdot B(A+B)^{-1}A=A^{-1}B(A+B)^{-1}A+\overbrace{(A+B)^{-1}A}^{=A^{-1}A(A+B)^{-1}A}=$$

$$A^{-1}\left(B+A\right)(A+B)^{-1}A=A^{-1}IA=I$$

Comment: I am not sure if this is valid statement : $(A^{-1}+B^{-1}).B(A+B)^{-1}A=A^{-1}B(A+B)^{-1}A+B^{-1}B(A+B)^{-1}A = (A^{-1}B+I)(A+B)^{-1}A$

Comment: @SamA What **exactly** you think isn't valid? And I recognize the first step in my answer but not the second one...

Comment: #DonAntonia, I meant the validity of my solution. Thank you for participating.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A positive diagonal matrix is positive definite too. Therefore $A+B$ is positive definite and in turn invertible. So, $(A+B)^{-1}$ exists and the identity is applicable.

Comment: Thank you user1551 for your answer.