# Prove that $A^{-1} + B^{-1}$ nonsingular by showing that $(A^{-1} + B^{-1} )^{-1} = A( A + B )^{-1} B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let $A$, $B$, and $A + B$ be nonsingular matrices. Prove that $A^{-1} + B^{-1}$  is nonsingular by showing that

$( A^{-1} + B^{-1} )^{-1}  = A( A + B )^{-1}  B$
I have done progress to only knowing that  $( A^{-1} + B^{-1} )^{-1} = (A + B)$
and from there am lost completely.
Someone please give me pointers

Comment: What means $A(A^ + B^)^(-1)B$? Who are $x,y$ in $A(A^{x}+B^{y})B$?

Comment: @Georgy Douglas: If you are happy with the given answer, then accept it, please. Otherwise your question remains open indefinitely.

Comment: Sorry, yeah am satisfied with the answer thank you

Comment: @GeorgyDouglas See the little grey tick mark under my answer's score? If you press that, it'll turn green, I'll get 15 reputation, and the question is considered "settled" in that you're officially happy with your answer and not actively looking for new answers. That's what Moritz was referring to by "accepting" the answer. I have more than enough reputation, but I agree in principle: if you're done with a question, it's a good idea to award a tick to your most helpful answer.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1505628/321264

Answer (score 1):

To show that $A(A + B)^{-1} B$ is the inverse to $A^{-1} + B^{-1}$, you need to verify the definition of inverses. Specifically, we call the matrix $C$ the inverse of $A^{-1} + B^{-1}$ if
$$C(A^{-1} + B^{-1}) = (A^{-1} + B^{-1})C = I.$$
If such a matrix $C$ exists, then it must be unique, hence why we can call it **the** inverse.

That is, we just need to show,
$$A(A + B)^{-1} B(A^{-1} + B^{-1}) = (A^{-1} + B^{-1})A(A + B)^{-1} B = I.$$

This is a little daunting to do as written. First note that
$$A(A + B)^{-1} B + A(A + B)^{-1} A = A(A + B)^{-1}(A + B) = AI = A,$$
hence
$$A(A + B)^{-1} B = A - A(A + B)^{-1} A.$$
Similarly,
$$A(A + B)^{-1} B = B - B(A + B)^{-1} B.$$
Hence,
\begin{align*}
(A^{-1} + B^{-1})A(A + B)^{-1} B &= A^{-1} (A(A + B)^{-1} B) + B^{-1} (A(A + B)^{-1} B) \\
&= A^{-1}(A - A(A + B)^{-1} A) + B^{-1}(B - B(A + B)^{-1} B) \\
&= I - (A + B)^{-1} A + I - (A + B)^{-1} B \\
&= 2I - (A + B)^{-1} (A + B) \\
&= I.
\end{align*}
See if you can show that
$$A(A + B)^{-1} B(A^{-1} + B^{-1}) = I$$
in a similar manner!

Comment: Thank you so much this really cleared things up.Again thank you