# Show that $A^{-1} + B^{-1}$ is invertible when $A,B$ and $A+B$ are invertible

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I have the following issue: $A,B\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ invertible, such that also $A + B$ is invertible. How is it shown that $A^{-1} + B^{-1}$ is invertible?

Comment: See the [introduction to posting mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Can we fix the title ?

Comment: @Andreu Gooz Biel: If your question has been answered below, please, accept an answer. Otherwise your question remains open indefinitely. Thank you!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1505628/321264

Answer (score 8):

$$
A^{-1}+B^{-1} = A^{-1}(A+B)B^{-1}
$$
By the way: (Spanish) demonstración --> (English) proof. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Of course you know that a square matrix has a two sided inverse if you have found an inverse from one side.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more pedantic approach to @amsmath's slick approach:

Suppose we want to solve $(A^{-1} + B^{-1}) x = A^{-1}x + B^{-1} x = y$.

Then $Ay=x + AB^{-1} x $, and letting $x'=B^{-1} x$ we get
$Ay = B x' + A x' = (A+B)x'$ and so $x'= (A+B)^{-1} Ay$ and finally
$x=Bx' = B(A+B)^{-1} Ay$.

Hence $(A^{-1} + B^{-1})^{-1} = B(A+B)^{-1} A$.