# Inverse of sum of inverses of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, positive-definite

Is it somehow possible to reformulate the following exuation into something easier to calculate:

$$(A^{-1}+ B^{-1})^{-1}$$

A and B are both square real matrices: $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$,
and are positive definite and therefore invertible.

Comment: What’s a quadratic matrix? Is that the same as symmetric?

Comment: I don't think so as the sum is not neccessarily invertible (take A = Id = A^-1 and B = -Id = B^-1)

Comment: By quadratic matrix did you mean square matrix?

Comment: Oh, I get it: quadratic = second power = square. I thought quadratic was a reference to quadratic form, meaning a symmetric matrix.

Comment: @Joe More likely it's that "quadrata" is the word for square in Italian

Comment: [Related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1505628/81360)

Comment: @joe Sorry for the confusion, yes i meant square matrix when writing quadratic. Its adapted now

Comment: @Stockfish, thanks for pointing out, i adapted the problem to positive definite matrices.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Note that
$$
A^{-1}(A + B)B^{-1}
 = A^{-1}AB^{-1} + A^{-1}BB^{-1} = B^{-1} + A^{-1}.
$$
That is, we have
$$
A^{-1} + B^{-1} = A^{-1}(A + B)B^{-1} \implies
(A^{-1} + B^{-1})^{-1} = B(A + B)^{-1}A.
$$
If you prefer, this can also equal to $A(A + B)^{-1}B$.

Note that because $A,B$ are positive definite, $A + B$ is also positive definite and therefore invertible.

Comment: Furthermore, we can't expect to get any other expressions, because the special case for $1\times1$ matrices has to be $AB(A+B)^{-1}$, so the general case must use these three factors. +1.

Comment: The first line should read $A^{-1}(A+B)B^{-1} = A^{-1}AB^{-1} + A^{-1}BB^{-1} = B^{-1} + A^{-1}$