# Matrix derivative of $\mathrm{tr}((I+X^{-1})^{-1})$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, inverse, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

I'm trying to calculate the derivative of $\mathrm{tr}((I+X^{-1})^{-1})$ with respect to $X$. By some sort of a chain rule, I believe this should be $X^{-1}(I+X^{-1})^{-2}X^{-1}$. However, I'm having a hard time finding a good reference for such a result. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe P154 of this (in general, search matrix calculus or vector calculus) mason.gmu.edu/~jgentle/csi771/13f/matrixcalculus.pdf

Comment: maybe P154 of this (in general, search matrix calculus or vector calculus) mason.gmu.edu/~jgentle/csi771/13f/matrixcalculus.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative approach to Ben Grossmann's approach

We will use the following Frobenius product identity
\begin{align}
\operatorname{tr}\left(A^T B \right) := A:B .
\end{align}

Further, we will use the differential of invertible (and assuming symmetric) matrix $X$
\begin{align}
XX^{-1} = I \Longrightarrow dX X^{-1} + X dX^{-1} = 0 \Longleftrightarrow dX^{-1} = -X^{-1} dX X^{-1}.
\end{align}

Let us define the following matrix with their differential
\begin{align}
M := \left(I + X^{-1} \right) \Longrightarrow dM = dX^{-1} = -X^{-1} dX X^{-1}.
\end{align}

To this end, say $f := \operatorname{tr}\left( M^{-1} \right)$, then we find differential followed by the gradient.
\begin{align}
df 
&= d\operatorname{tr}\left( M^{-1} \right) = d\operatorname{tr}\left( I M^{-1} \right) \\
&= I : dM^{-1} \\
&= I : -M^{-1} dM M^{-1} \\
&= - M^{-2} : dM \\
&= - M^{-2} : -X^{-1} dX X^{-1} \\
&= X^{-1}  M^{-2} X^{-1}  : dX 
\end{align}

Then the gradient is
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} = X^{-1}  M^{-2} X^{-1} = X^{-1}  \left(I + X^{-1} \right)^{-2} X^{-1} .
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Define the matrix function
$$\eqalign{
&F = (I+X^{-1})^{-1} = X(I+X)^{-1} \\
&F + (I+X)^{-1} = (I+X)(I+X)^{-1} \;\doteq\; I \\ 
}$$
and its differential$$\eqalign{
F &= I - (I+X)^{-1} \\
dF &= (I+X)^{-1}dX\,(I+X)^{-1} \\
}$$
Then calculate the differential and the gradient of its trace.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= {\rm Tr}(F) \\
d\phi
 &= {\rm Tr}(dF) \\
 &= {\rm Tr}\Big((I+X)^{-1}dX\,(I+X)^{-1}\Big) \\
 &= {\rm Tr}\Big((I+X)^{-2}dX\Big) \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X} &= (I+X)^{-2} \\
}$$

Answer (score 2):

We can make life much easier if we use [this matrix identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3757617/81360) to rewrite
$$
(I + X^{-1})^{-1} = X(I + X)^{-1}.
$$
Now, we compute the derivative of $f(X) = X(I + X)^{-1}$ in "differential form" as follows.
$$
df = d[X(I + X)^{-1}] = dX(I + X)^{-1} + X d(I + X)^{-1}\\
= dX(I + X)^{-1} - X(I + X)^{-1}d(I + X)(I + X)^{-1}\\
= dX(I + X)^{-1} - X(I + X)^{-1}dX(I + X)^{-1}\\
= [I - X(I + X)^{-1}]dX(I + X)^{-1}.
$$
Thus, we have
$$
d\operatorname{tr}(f(X)) = 
\operatorname{tr}[[I - X(I + X)^{-1}]dX(I + X)^{-1}]\\
= \operatorname{tr}[(I + X)^{-1}[I - X(I + X)^{-1}]dX].
$$
We can now convert from [differential form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Identities_in_differential_form) to get the numerator-layout derivative
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} = \left((I + X)^{-1}[I - X(I + X)^{-1}]\right)^\top.
$$
The denominator-layout version is the same, but without the transpose. If we use the fact that all rational functions of $X$ commute, we can simplify the expression a bit:
$$
(I + X)^{-1}[I - X(I + X)^{-1}] = \\
[I - X(I + X)^{-1}](I + X)^{-1} = \\
[(I + X) - X](I + X)^{-2} =\\
(I + X)^{-2}.
$$
That is, the derivative is either $(I + X)^{-2}$ or $[(I + X)^{-2}]^\top$, depending on your convention.